# Testing out an old camera - why have the scans come out like this?

Tags: film, medium-format

Found an old Goldeck medium format camera which I tested with a couple of rolls of film. Nearly all of the scans have come out this way even using different focus lengths. The last shot of the second roll came out well, but that was it. [image]
Does anyone know what has caused this and whether its an easy fix? Thanks

Comment: I guess it will be difficult to answer your question unless you tell what you have tried to photograph and how the image was supposed to be.

Comment: Can't be sure exactly what this was as they all look the same but likely just trees etc as took them whilst on a walk

Comment: "Nearly all the scans have come out this way" What way? What are you seeing here? It looks like _something_. Who did the scans? What kind of film? Do you have a lightbox? Can you take a photo of the film sitting on the lightbox? It's very hard for anyone to diagnose anything based on the image you've included. Can you include the frame that came out well too?